# How can I remove all containers by image name and do nothing if it already removed

Tags: bash, docker

I have bash script which stops and remove all docker container by image name.
I can stop and remove all docker container by image name by single command

```
docker rm  $(docker stop $( docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=image_name))
```

But if container not exist this expression `docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=image_name` not returns nothing and `docker stop` command fails. How can I remove all containers by image name and do nothing if it already removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
for i in $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=image_name); do docker rm $(docker stop $i); done
```

It should only call `docker rm` if `docker ps` returns results.  Works in my environment.